# Problemas con Responsive en DataTable JS

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, vb.net, datatables

Buen día para todos,

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Estoy elaborando un Tipo de Tablero mediante un Datatable, este funcionada perfecto hace rato, casi como 2 años estaba bien, pero de un momento a otro empezó a salir  de manera visual defectuoso, busco el error , pero no me sale nada, elimine y volví a subir las librerías y tampoco. Estoy utilizando .Net y JS para elaborarlo.

No se si alguno me pueda colaborar con el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: checa la version de dt a ver si tienes la ultima o version especifica..

Comment: Hola, ya hasta coloque la ultima versión de datatable y aun así me sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: con revisar la version, me referia a que algunas veces como el cdn que tienes apunta directo a la ultima version y no una especifica. al actualizar ciertas cosas cambian y se descuadran intenta buscar la version especifica anterior y probar con esta!